# ¿Como convertir de numeros a letras en un determinado formato en PHP?

Tags: php

lo que quiero hacer es convertir un numero a letras en un formato especifico, por ejemplo si tengo el siguiente numero `1096.93` que esto se transforma a `UN MIL NOVENTA Y SEIS 93/100 SOLES`. Investigue una forma de hacer que es usando el `NumberFormatter` pero esta funcion solo me devuelve los numero de cada uno y aun nose como pasar a ese formato

```
<?php
NumberFormatter("es", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT) //Funcion nativa para convertir numeros a letras
?>
```

Otra forma de hacerlo es buscar librerias, pero soy nuevo en php y nose cual podria utilizar. Una cosa mas aclarar si esto sirve, estoy utilizando `Laravel 5.3`

Comment: @BetaM la vercion de laravel no varia no? laravel 5.8 - laravel 5.3

Comment: No sé, no lo he necesitado usar, te recomiendo pruebes y nos comentas